# How to replace cmd with powershell on windows 10 when the option is greyed out?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

Is there a way I can toggle this option when the toggle switch is disabled in the settings GUI of Windows 10?

[image]

Ironically, I want powershell to be default but contrary to the greyed out option in the image, the command prompt is currently the default option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option will be grayed out if disabled by Group Policy. The responsible policy setting is "Prevent users from replacing the Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu they see when they right-click the lower-left corner or press the Windows logo key+X" in the *Windows Components | Edge UI* category under the Administrative Templates branch of user configuration. (The policy's unique ID is `Microsoft.Policies.EdgeUI:ShowCommandPromptOnWinX`.) Setting that policy to Enabled creates the behavior you've encountered; setting it to Disabled or leaving it Not Configured yields the normal behavior.

If it's not enabled in Group Policy, it must be in the Registry, specifically in this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI
```

The responsible value is `ShowCommandPromptOnWinX`. Set it to 0 or delete it to restore the switch in Settings. Changes may require a logoff/logon cycle to take effect.

Comment: If it *is* set as a corporate policy, ask IT rather than change it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Another register we can modify after set the ***prevent users from replace command prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu...*** as not configured：

Registry path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Value: DontUsePowerShellOnWinx

Data Value: 0 (32-bit dword)

Reboot the machine.

Comment: Yes, we need modify the register first in the path: User Configuration \   Administrative Templates \Windows Components \ Edge UI and we can modified the register to replace CMD with PowerShell.